# Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet is not working?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3-java

I need test ethereum for my pet project.

I go to https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ , put a link with my tweet with my Ethereum address in MetaMask, choose `3 Ethers / 8 hours`.[image]

The request was accepted, but 17 hours past and I haven't my test ethers.
[image]
Did I something wrong or I must wait a little longer?
And explanation me please, what exactly means 3 Ethers / 8 hours?

Comment: Came here to say that it's still not working. Not sure to whom we can raise this feedback.

Comment: Although this is a good question, my guess is it was closed because it doesn't belong in this forum. It belongs here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not working; it's down for a while (not sure when it's gonna come back up).

"3 Ethers / 8 hours" means that you can only request 3 Ethers each 8 hours.

You can get .001 ether here though: http://rinkeby-faucet.com/

It's not much but still better than nothing. I think the cooldown is only 1 or 2 hours.

If you want more than .001 faster they only block requests by IP, so ask a friend or something to open the link with your address and you'll get .001 more.

Answer (score 12):

Many times I've received 0.1 testnet ETH from this faucet:

[Rinkeby ETH](https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby)

The above link will send you fairly quickly either Rinkeby ETH or Rinkeby Link or BOTH.

Also, here's an up to date list of ETH faucets:
[doc.chain.link](https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/)

(look for Rinkeby)

Comment: this is not ETH, it is chainlink token

Comment: Nulik, the above link will send you fairly quickly either Rinkeby ETH or Rinkeby Link or BOTH.