# How to get test ether for pet project as of 9/20/21 when primary rinkeby faucet webpages do not work?

Tags: testing, project, ether

I have tried both of these links but neither one appears to work:

https://faucet.rinkeby.io/
According to this post it is not working:
[Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428769/rinkeby-authenticated-faucet-is-not-working)
I have tried on two separate addresses and its been several days and has not worked for me.

This one also appears to not work
http://rinkeby-faucet.com/
'No funds avaialable' error appears in red

Any suggestions on how to get some of that sweet, sweet faucet test ether??

Comment: Looks like faucet.rinkeby.io quite regularly fails to fund during high-demand periods such as weekends. Tried it again on a slow weekday and voila, got some sweet. sweet faucet ether.

The 2nd link regularly gets emptied out by bots.